# indices not reading properly

Tags: java, arrays, indices

The code is cutting adding a space in the first array position (0) and starting the word on the second position (1).  The last letter of the word therefore gets cut of because the length of the array is determined by the word length itself.

The input word is `"hummus"`, but the output is `" hummu"` (notice the leading space).

My code (some variables are declared above in a different section of code):

```
//Reads in the wordlist
for (int x = 0; x < wordList.length; x++) {
    word = wordList[x];
}

//Splits the word chosen from word list into an array
JTextField[] wordAmount = new JTextField[word.length()];//Creates a JtextField for each letter
String[] letters = word.split("");
String temp;
int wordLength = word.length();

//Determines amount of textfields are needed for the word
for (int j = 0; j < wordLength; j ++) {
    temp = letters[j];
    wordAmount[j] = new JTextField();
    wordAmount[j].setText(temp);
    System.out.println(wordAmount[j].getText());
}## Heading ##
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty easy to step through with a debugger.  I don't have Java set up on the computer I'm currently on, but I'm pretty sure your problem is with this line:

```
String[] letters = word.split("");
```

I think this is going to pick up an extraneous space on both ends.

This is a very odd way to split a `String` into its letters; why not just use `toCharArray` and convert each `char` to a `String`?

---

As a side note, what exactly are you expecting

```
for (int x = 0; x < wordList.length; x++) {
    word = wordList[x];
}
```

to do?

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever pass an empty String to split.  Like @MattPutnam said, use [`toCharArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) to get the individual characters of an array.  You can turn a `char` back into a `String` using the static `Character.toString` method when you need to.

String's .split with `""` as the regex matches anything... which kicks in this rule:

> When there is a positive-width match at the beginning of the input sequence then an empty leading substring is included at the beginning of the resulting array.

Since "" matches the first letter of your String, `letters[0]` is set to an empty string.

Comment: Also, I probably should go back and note that by "matching everything" I actually mean the character delimiter between items.